# How to get permission to get access to the LinkedIn Profile API?

Tags: linkedin-api, bubble.io

I want to understand how to get authorization/permission on this LinkedIn Profile API.

I recorded a video to help better explain my issue/question: https://www.loom.com/share/d34ae7f33f6948fb95177d213ada816c?sid=4ebda989-e334-47be-babc-61fe860ef3fb

I want to get all of a profiles information from the LinkedIn profile API, however, it says it is reserved for some users with granted permission, would like to understand more about this.

Comment: Ask the company about their offerings.  https://business.linkedin.com heck, if you make an account, you'll probably have someone from linkedin clamoring to take your money in exchange for getting you other peoples' info.